# Can you explain the purpose of a double tilde in this if statement?

Tags: php

I came across this in some code I am modifying and don't know it's purpose.

```
if($configuration_value === '~~' || $duplicateValue->RecordCount() != 0){
```

I've not seen this used before and searching SO and a popular search engine didn't bring up any answers.

Can anyone explain the functionality of === '~~'  ?

Comment: It's just a string, it doesn't have any special meaning.

Comment: It's apparently a special value used in your configuration data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case `~~` is just a string it doesn't have a specific meaning and coming towards

`===` it checks that the value and type of both the sides are equal or not.